# I need a regex to match first sentence of the string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to come up with a regex which would match the first sentence of the string. I don't need anything too complex, just a sentence that ends with ". " or "! " or "? " note the space after, so that the sentence "I need this domain.com! " would match. I didn't find anything on regexlib.com either.
So far I'm stuck with this:

```
([^.|?|!]*)[\.\s\?\s\!\s]
```

It's not really working. If I try to match

```
"I need this domain.com! Another sentence. And another sentence."
```

I only get "I need this domain." and I need it to be "I need this domain.com!"

Comment: Which Language? I doubt regex is there correct way to go here though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this :

```
^.*?[\.!\?](?:\s|$)
```

Comment: I will accept it, but for some reason I have to wait. Besides, let's be fair, I only accept correct answers.

Comment: It won't work for `'This is first (e.g. 1st) sentence. And the second one.'`

Answer (score 6):

Here is a pattern which passes the original test while also addressing Vitali Ponomar's comment about parentheses on manji's answer.

```
^.*?[.!?](?:\s|$)(?!.*\))
```

This uses a [negated lookahead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-negated-look-ahead) to effectively say:

1. Start at the beginning and match any characters, any number of times, but as few times as possible which still allows the following to hold true.
2. We see one of these characters: `.` *or* `?` *or* `!`
3. It's followed by: a white space character *or* the end of the line
4. Which **is not** followed by anything that leads up to a `)` closing parenthesis character.

This takes advantage of the fact that we know where the parentheses group ends as long as it is balanced. So it could fail if the sentence is malformed due to user input or bad processing, etc.

You can add a certain degree of protection by asserting that the "beginning of a sentence" marker must include an uppercase character.

```
^.*?[.!?](?:\s[A-Z]|$)(?!.*\))
```

The reason this is desirable is because, in most programs, it is significantly easier to capitalize strings before concatenating them vs ensuring parentheses are properly balanced within them.

Note that because the OP accepted an answer using a [non-capturing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-non-capturing-parentheses) group, like `(?:foo)`, I have also used one. This will cause the "beginning of a sentence" marker to be included in the match. You may or may not want this, depending on whether you are going to rely upon only the white space character or my added capitalization check.

My recommendation is to not include it and you can do that by using a [lookahead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-lookahead) instead, like `(?=foo)`.

```
^.*?[.!?](?=\s[A-Z]|$)(?!.*\))
```

Now that we aren't including cruft in the match, let's take care of the case where there is nothing but a space after our first sentence:

```
^.*?[.!?](?=\s[A-Z]|\s?$)(?!.*\))
```

Now some tests with this pretty decent pattern:

- **Input**: "I need this domain.com! Another sentence. And another sentence."

  **Match**: "I need this domain.com!"
- **Input**: "This is first (e.g. 1st) sentence. And the second one."

  **Match**: "This is first (e.g. 1st) sentence."
- **Input**: "This is a broken (e.g. 1st sentence. And the second one."

  **Match**: "This is a broken (e.g. 1st sentence."
- **Input**: "This trips up ... most. But not me."

  **Match**: "This trips up ... most."

Great. But there are still places where this falls down. For example: quotation marks. Sentences are complicated! To do this right, you really need to take into account the entire punctuation rules of the given language and then come up with an algorithm which does not assume everyone will always follow them perfectly, and makes certain parts optional without introducing weird matches. Once you go down that route, you end up with a long, unreadable expression with lots of [greed operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-questionmark) (certain uses of the `?` question mark).

In the end, it mostly comes down to what the input of your program is like, where it is coming from, and how well you can pre-processs it before applying complicated pattern matching to it. Often it is more reliable and more readable, though less performant, to do multiple passes of smaller, simpler patterns. One to remove or de-duplicate stuff you don't care about (like line breaks or other white space characters), then one to remove possible traces of malicious input, ... etc. Slowly getting more complicated as the input simplifies.

Comment: Thanks! After banging my head against a wall trying to amend my existing regex which thought that the "D." in "D.C." in the middle of a sentence was the end of it, I finally found your regex, which was the only one that handled that fairly simple case!

Comment: I'm testing it at https://regex101.com/r/d0ZpPF/1 and quotation marks seem to work there.

Answer (score 2):

Have not tested but this should do it

```
^([^.|?|!]+)
```

The problem is that * matches zero or more chars, whereas + matches at least one char

Answer (score 1):

(I'm going to write with Java regex syntax, since that's what I know; it ought to be the same for our purposes here as any other regex system you're using but I'm not 100% sure.)

The regex for a sentence boundary is evidently `[.!?]\s`. So, you want to match everything up to that first one. ".+" matches greedily and matches everything up to the start of the last sentence. You want a reluctant capture:

`(.+?)[.!?]\s`